# issue with the sorting arrow in ng-table header

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have an issue with the ng-table header : the sorting arrow doesn't show . the sorting is working fine.[image]

The first row is just for grouping.
In this exemple data is sorted by ID but the arrow indicating the sorting order doesn't appear.

Template header code :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="header_template.html">
 
   <tr>
   <th colspan="2"></th>

   <th colspan="3">Gross</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>

  <th ng-repeat="column in columns" 
      class="text-center sortable" ng-class="{
                      'sorting' : column.field,
                     'sort-asc': fundTableParam.isSortBy(column.field, 'asc'),
                     'sort-desc': fundTableParam.isSortBy(column.field, 'desc')
        }"

      ng-click="fundTableParam.sorting(column.field, fundTableParam.isSortBy(column.field, 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc')">
      {{column.title}}
      
       
 
  </th>
  </tr>
   
    <tr ng-show="show_filter" class="ng-table-filters">
    <th ng-repeat="column in columns"  class="filter">
        <div ng-repeat="(name, filter) in column.filter">
            <div ng-if="column.filterTemplateURL" ng-show="column.filterTemplateURL">
              <div ng-include="column.filterTemplateURL"></div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!column.filterTemplateURL" ng-show="!column.filterTemplateURL">
                <div ng-include="'ng-table/filters/' + filter + '.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are missing the CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet"; href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.css">
```